# Sentiment analysis of food reviews based on '!' and adding punctuation marks to wordcloud?

Tags: python, word-cloud

I am making a sentiment analysis on a food review data and noticed that if the review has an '!' in it the review tends to be positive. So I am planning to predict the rating of the review based on the comment, if it involves '!' the rating will be higher. 
I generated a wordcloud for the positive reviews but it does noot involve punctuation marks. Is there a way to show '!' in the wordcloud or print out the count of exclamation points in positive reviews?

Comment: what type of word cloud have you used?

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a dataframe like this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sentiment': ['positive', 'positive', 'negative', 'positive'], 'sentence': ['This is cool!', 'this is ok', 'not very cool', '!!!']})

    sentiment   sentence
0   positive    This is cool!
1   positive    this is ok
2   negative    not very cool
3   positive    !!!
```

You would want to slice the positives and then count the ocurences of `!` (as I get it):

```
df[df['sentiment'] == 'positive'].sentence.str.count('!').sum()
```

Result:

> 4

Comment: I am using a worldcloud from the WordCloud module: this is what I tried but it gives invalid type comparison error. df[df['Score'] == '5'].Summary.str.count('!').sum()

Comment: can you provide a sample in your question, so I can experiment with something real

Comment: I got the data from here: https://www.kaggle.com/premvardhan/amazon-fine-food-reviews-analysis-using-knn/data and this is how I wrote the wordcloud: posWords = ' '.join(list(df[df['Score'] == 5]['Summary']))
pos_wc = WordCloud(width = 512,height = 512).generate(posWords)
plt.figure(figsize = (10, 8), facecolor = 'k')
plt.imshow(pos_wc)
plt.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout(pad = 0)
plt.show()